# Dynamically Changing the CSS

Tags: jquery, css, dynamic, hyperlink

I have created a matrix of 5x5 boxes. I would like to click on a link and have that link dynamically change color after I have clicked it (a:visited) - one at a time. However, in my current code, it changes the color to all the links and not the specific one in which I have clicked.

HTML:

```
<ul id="rowOne" class="center">
    <li><a href="#">$100</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">$100</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">$100</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">$100</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">$100</a></li>
</ul>
```

Jquery:

```
$('a').click(function(){
$.each('a').css({'color':'#002290'});
});
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `$.each('a').css(..)` is redundant -- you don't need the `each()`, jquery will apply `.css()` to all matching elements.

Comment: Also (further to the answers), I'd suggest using `addClass()`/`removeClass()` rather than directly changing the CSS of the element(s).

Answer (score 7):

Your code says "When any `<a>` is clicked, iterate over **all** `<a>` elements (`$.each...`) and change their CSS". You need to apply your change only to the clicked element, which is available via `this` in jQuery's event callbacks:

```
$('a').click(function(){
  $(this).css({'color':'#002290'});
});
```

You can also omit quotation marks around the keys (`color`) when building an object (if the property doesn't contain hyphens)...

```
$(this).css({color: '#002290'});
```

... or omit the object entirely when you're setting a single attribute and pass the name and value as two separate string parameters:

```
$(this).css('color', '#002290');
```

Comment: Before applying color to current link,we have to remove previous clicked links..right ??

Comment: @Baadshah Maybe, but that's outside the scope of the question, and you're reading more into the question that the question asked for.

Answer (score 4):

You need to do this -

```
$('a').click(function(){
   $(this).css({'color':'#002290'});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you are changing for all the `a` tags again **.Dont Forget to remove all the tag colors before clicked.**

```
$('a').click(function(){    
   $('a').css('color', '');           
   $(this).css({'color':'#002290'});  //current tag
});
```